# Authlogic - Logout not working on production but working in dev?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authlogic

I have only just started to investigate... but thought I would throw this to the community as well.

I am building an app using Authlogic for authentication. The auth part is basically straight off the authlogic tutorials...

My logoff button works in dev, destroying the session and giving the flash on the root_url. However, on production the link spins, take me to the root_url, but no flash and the session data is still there.

Everything else works on production... like I said, I am just beginning to investigate. Hopefully someone has an idea...

Setup info:
Rails 2.3.2
Dev - standard script/server mongrel
Prod - apache/passenger/mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. Turns out there are some session issues with authlogic and versions of Passenger before 2.2.2.

I upgraded to 2.2.2 and the problem has been resolved.

So a quick upgrade and everything runs perfect.

Comment: Thanks for responding to yourself. I had the same issue. +1